# Perl module that works like Data::Dumper but allow data manipulation

Tags: perl, iterator, visitor-pattern, data-dumper

Is there a popular Perl module that works like `Data::Dumper` but allows user to write hook to manipulate the data inside complex structure or object.

There are a few modules showing up in google such as `Data::Visitor` or `Data::Structure::Util` that might do the job, but I'm not sure if they are the popular ones .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written Data::Dmap to do this, but as mentioned, `Data::Rmap`, `Data::Transformer` and `Data::Visitor` are also relevant.

The basic idea of `Data::Dmap` is that it allows you to transform anything in a nested data structure and still tries to behave like the built in map function.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure it is what you mean, but [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDump) supports hooks to filter dumped data. Similar hooks are also possible in [Data::Printer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aPrinter).

**Edit:** If you need editing, I would look at [Data::Rmap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aRmap) or [Data::Transformer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aTransformer). Also, if your structure is simple (say only scalars, hashes and arrays), you can make simple recursive traversal yourself.

Comment: well, what I need is to in-place modifying data in complex structure, such as replace 50 with 200 for all string values inside a structure (that may contain objects)

Answer (score -1):

`YAML` is a nice serialization format, easy to edit string values and such.  It might not handle all your objects, but it's worth a try, and it both serializes and reloads things easily.